# create table su AS select don't work

Tags: mysql

i have this table

```
ID  |user       |Contact   |Duration
1    asif        11         00
2    bob         22         65
3    cena        33         00
4    asif        44         00
5    cena        33         00
6    cena        33         00
7    bob         55         43
8    asif        44         33
9    bob         66         00
```

i want use this sql;

```
CREATE TABLE su
AS (select user, 
      contactcount,
      duration,
      case when durationcount = 0 then 0 else duration/durationcount end
from (
   select user, 
          count(distinct contact) contactcount,
          sum(duration) duration,
          sum(case when duration > 0 then 1 else 0 end) durationcount
   from table4
   group by user
) t)
```

But phpmyadmin, give error. `#1166 - Incorrect column name 'case when durationcount = 0 then 0 else duration/durationcount end'` 
expected ouput;

```
|user      |count   |duration_total    |case when durationcount = 0 then 0 else duration/durationcount end
 asif       2        33                 33
 bob        3        108                54
 cena       1        00                 00
```

what is wromg in this sql ?
the goal is to create new table whit ID, user, total duration per user and average time by user when duration >0

Comment: What error does it produce? Typically with a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT... `, the `SELECT` statement should not be surrounded in `(...)`  Syntax reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: Why do you not use a normal create table statement. this is the only opportunity to create a table with the right field types and the correct indexes

Comment: error code i got; #1166 - Incorrect column name 'case when durationcount = 0 then 0 else duration/durationcount end'